# Default page not fetched when pressing F5 in VS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm pressing F5 but the browser can't find any resources on the localhost. My controller has

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //ViewBag.Message = "This is a dynamical text.";
  return View();
}
```

but the line *locationhost:12345* in the URL doesn't hit the view. Not sure what I did but I'm certain it's something basic and very stupid.   :)

It's a vanilla project, VS 10, MVC 4.

The error is 404. Is the routing wrong? Everything is default set-up by the template...

Comment: Don't you mean  localhost:12345 ?

Comment: Did you make any change to the template project or you run it as it comes?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi No changes except for a line of text in the ASPX file telling *Hello cruel world*. ANd yes, I meant *localhost*. Typo.